# Is food contaminated with swarf due to polishing metal plates or sharpening knives safe for our body?

Tags: kitchen-safety

Swarf is a word for metal particles or debris produced in polishing metal with abrasive tools. For example, swarf can be produced when polishing teppanyaki grill or sharpening knives.

I often see Kebab sellers who don't wipe their knives after sharpening and cut cooked meat.  Teppanyaki grills are often polished but without washing them thoroughly. Without any doubt many people still consume such contaminated food as if it is safe.

Is it safe to eat food contaminated with swarf? Is there any scientific article that support the conclusion?

Comment: @AE: I am not sure the cooking experts in cooking.SE have scientific evidences to answer this question.

Comment: Is there anybody here can rephrase my question to meet the requirement to be on topic?

Comment: Are they sharpening, or are they honing?  Honing shouldn't be removing any metal, just pushing the blade back into alignment.

Comment: I closed it as a dupe, but I'm considering closing the old one too. Food safety is a matter of government regulation, and there is no rule against sharpening your knives. "Is it actually harmful" is a health related question, which we cannot answer.